# Compilation problem in the standard x86_64 libraries

Tags: c++, linker, compiler-errors

I am having trouble compiling a program I have written. I have two different files with the same includes but only one generates the following error when compiled with g++

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.10.1/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/elf/start.S:109: undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The files I am including in my header are as follows:

```
#include <google/sparse_hash_map>
using google::sparse_hash_map;

#include <ext/hash_map>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>

using std::priority_queue;
using std::stack;
using std::vector;

using __gnu_cxx::hash_map;
using __gnu_cxx::hash; 

using namespace std;
```

Searching the internet for those two lines hasn't resulted in anything to help me. I would be very grateful for any advice. Thank you

Comment: Could you give us the complete source, or at least a few lines before main() in the file that fails to compile?

Comment: Hey all thanks for the tips. I followed some of your advice and realized that I didn't understand the need for a main the way I was programming. Thought I could just compile as a function. Seems I have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `main` function and you don't have one. If you *do* have a `main` function, show more code please.

Answer (score 4):

To build *two separate programs* you need both source files to define `main()` function.

To build a *single program* out of two source files - first compile each file with `-c` options (compile only) - you will get two `.o` files, then *link* these files together. Something like this:

```
$ g++ -Wall -pedantic -ggdb -O -c -o module0.o module0.cpp
$ g++ -Wall -pedantic -ggdb -O -c -o module1.o module1.cpp
$ g++ -Wall -pedantic -ggdb -O -o prog module0.o module1.o
```

to build binary `prog` from two source files.

If you need to link with some library, you'll have to point compiler to it's headers with `-I` and to objects with `-L` flags, then tell the linker to actually reference the library with `-l`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `main` is not defined. Do you have one defined for your second program? Can you post more details about the source body that fails to link?

Comment: Thanks. That was all I needed to figure out why my code wasn't working. Needed to define a main just to call my function.